# Unable to login as the service principal - Tomcat SSO to Active Directory

Tags: java, active-directory, tomcat7, kerberos, spnego

Am trying to set up a Single Sign for my spring web application and am using **Tomcat 7.0.63** to set it up **SSO**, and **am new to this concept**. I have did setup of active directory and have configured the set up with AD, DNS and DHCP and I have created the domain also **(Domain name : sampledomain.net)** in **Windows Server 2012 r2**.

Under the domain have registered the users and I can **able** to **login** from the **client machine** with the **domain users**. Now am trying to set up SSO by one of the user which is registered in **AD users**.

I have created SPN for the user with the name of **tomcatuser@SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET** this is the **PRINCIPAL NAME** for the user I have created. By go through some of articles in online I have set up those step by step.

Now am getting the error like **GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)** when the tomcat trying to resolve the user which registered for SPN.

I have attached my config files and the error which I getting below :

**file : krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm=SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET
default_keytab_name="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample/tomcat.keytab"
default_txt_enctypes=aes256-cts-hmac-shal-96,aes128-cts-hmac-shal-96
default_tgs_enctypes=aes256-cts-hmac-shal-96,aes128-cts-hmac-shal-96
forwardable=true

[realms]
INFOMINDZ.NET={
 kdc=sampledomain.net:88
}

[domain_realm]
sampledomain.net=sampledomain.net
.sampledomain.net=sampledomain.net
```

**file jaas.conf**

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  doNotPrompt=false
  principal="HTTP/tomcatuser@SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET"
  storeKey=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample\tomcat.keytab"
  useTicketCache=true
  isInitiator=false
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  clearPass=false
  useFirstPass=true
  debug=true;
};
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  doNotPrompt=false
  principal="HTTP/tomcatuser@SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET"
  storeKey=true
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample\tomcat.keytab"
  useTicketCache=false
  isInitiator=false
  refreshKrb5Config=true
  clearPass=false
  useFirstPass=true
  debug=true;
};
```

**file : web.xml**  Have added the login config as below

```
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Tomcat Manager Application</realm-name>
    <auth-method>SPNEGO</auth-method>
  </login-config>
```

**file : server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="OFF"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <!--connectionURL="ldap://dc.infomindz.net:389" -->
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" maxSavePostSize="2097152" URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
            maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
                connectionURL="ldap://X.X.X.X:389" 
                userSubtree="true"
                userBase="cn=Users,dc=infomindz,dc=net" 
                userSearch="(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})"/>
                <!--userRoleName="memberOf" 
                roleBase="cn=Users,dc=infomindz,dc=net" 
                roleName="cn"
                roleSearch="(member={0})" 
                roleSubtree="true" 
                roleNested="true"-->

            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
                <Context docBase="ROOT.war" path="">
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator"
                    loginConfigName="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.accept"
                        storeDelegatedCredential="true" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Those above are my configuration in my Tomcat for SSO. When I try to open the page **http://localhost:8080/manager/html** as usual manager prompts for the username and password. As I have configured as SSO am wondering why tomcat prompting me to provide username and password.

Usually before setup SSO we use username and password for this type of prompting as admin and admin123. But if I give so not accepting and throws the below exception I don't know whether the Tomcat has communicated with LDAP or not with the user **tomcatuser@SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET**.

The error is :

```
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AcceptAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AcceptAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:327)
    ... 15 more
```

As from the exception I think some privilege is missing like, but I have created the user **tomcatuser** by copy the **administrator** user.

Anybody got any excpetion like this before and if you found the solution for this or anybody knows why this exception occurs please post your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably fixable based on the sheer amount of information you've provided here; great job on that part.  That said, I've noted some inconsistencies here, which will cause it to never work.  First and foremost, starting with your AD domain name:  is it INFOMINDZ.NET, or is it SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET?

Comment: That's not the way AD expects you to define SPNs. The resulting LDAP fields should look like `name: AnythingYouWant` `servicePrincipalName: HTTP/host.running.tomcat` `userPrincipalName: HTTP/host.running.tomcat@REALM.IN.KERBEROS.SYNTAX`

Comment: ...then your Tomcat instance on that specific host shall authenticate to the KDC (i.e. the AD server) as user `AnythingYouWant` *(yes, if you have multiple servers, you must create different SPNs; and you must use the canonical DNS host names, not aliases)* while client shall get Kerberos service tickets for service `HTTP` on that specific host using the KDC for that specific realm. If you have multiple AD domains (i.e. multiple KDC realms) then you have also to define KDC relationships in the client-side conf files.

Comment: T Heron the domain name is SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET only thats my mistake and have look up on it and have changed. But also getting the same error.

Comment: Samson there is no multiple AD server. I have configured a single AD server alone and you mentioned about user principal name instead of syntax can you give me some example for the `userPrincipalName` and `servicePrincipalName`.

Comment: What is the actual DNS host name of your Tomcat server - is it something like *server01.sampledomain.net*?  If so, change your SPN to:  *HTTP/server01.sampledomain.net@SAMPLEDOMAIN.NET* in jaas.conf.  And you'll need a keytab having this SPN, and the SPN will need to be associated with the AD account *tomcatuser*.

Comment: T-Heron the tomcat server and the DNS server all in same server only.

Comment: Does your C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample\tomcat.keytab contain an SPN:  HTTP/server01.sampledomain.net?  If not, then Kerberos SSO to AD through Tomcat will never work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: GSSException: Defective token detected (Mechanism level: GSSHeader did not find the right tag)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSHeader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AcceptAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:340)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator$AcceptAction.run(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:327)
    ... 15 more
```

typically means that the browser sent an NTLM token instead of a Kerberos token in the SPNEGO handshake.

After requesting the application, use 'klist' or 'kerbtray' on the client side to check the Kerberos credential cache if the client really received a Kerberos service ticket for the server.

Comment: Bernhard - you are correct browser sending NTLM token instead of SPNEGO. I printed the log of the token in catalina log. The log I got is `NTLMSSP    —‚â                ±   ` like this. So how can I change this to SPNEGO token??

Comment: Do I need to configure any other thing in tomcat?

Comment: SPNEGO is only the protocol / mechanism to exchange tokens of any format. There is no standard way yet to force the client (browser) to ONLY send a Kerberos token. Internet Explorer will just send an NTLM token if it could not acquire a Kerberos token, other browsers just do not participate in SPNEGO if they can not acquire a Kerberos token.